# How to increment build number using fastlane and jenkins for iOS CICD setup?

Tags: jenkins, fastlane

I am using fastlane and jenkins for my iOS CICD setup. I used a command **increment_build_number** in my fastfile in order to increment the build number for every internal deployment to crashlytics.

Initially it was incrementing the **Bundle version** in info.plist and not **Bundle version string,short**. In the middle, i changed the **Bundle version string,short** to 1.0.0 in Xcode in order to test whether this will change the **Bundle version string,short** to 1.0.1 during next deployment .

After this **increment_build_number** is not at all working and it is not incrementing either the **Bundle version** nor the **Bundle version string,short**.

I couldn't find what is the issue here. Are we not suppose to change any of the bundle version in Xcode manually and how to fix this again?

Comment: I found the issue. The increment_build_number gets the current project version and increment the number in project under workspace directory but what about the local directory that i am working on? It is not updating that. So in my local every time i push it, the same build number will be there and on incrementing the same number again, i would get same build number  + 1 for each build. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the versioning settings in Xcode -
Xcode -> Target -> Build Settings -> Search for Versioning

- Change Versioning System to Apple Generic
- Set Current Project Version to a version value you want to start
  For Example, Current Project Version = 1

[image]

In Fastlane script you can pick from below as per your requirement :

```
 increment_version_number # Automatically increment patch version number

 increment_version_number(
 bump_type: "patch" # Automatically increment patch version number
 )

 increment_version_number(
 bump_type: "minor" # Automatically increment minor version number
 )

 increment_version_number(
 bump_type: "major" # Automatically increment major version number
 )

 increment_version_number(
 version_number: "2.1.1" # Set a specific version number
 )

 increment_version_number(
 version_number: "2.1.1",      # specify specific version number (optional, 
 omitting it increments patch version number)
 xcodeproj: "./path/to/MyApp.xcodeproj"  # (optional, you must specify the 
 path to your main Xcode project if it is not in the project root directory)
 )
```

Comment: increment build version and version number is not the same thing